# Bind EIP to an ECS cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, amazon-vpc, elastic-ip

I want all outbound traffic coming from my ECS cluster to using a single EIP.

I know I could setup a nat gateway. BUT is there an ECS feature that makes this easier or more built in? Or could I use like a VPC endpoint on the ECS cluster or something? Or is the solution still just setup a nat gateway and create a route to route all traffic from each individual EC2 instance in the cluster outbound to the nat gateway?

Edit: I think in my ecs service I could use an nlb with eip attached